# Registering a new controller for a dynamically loaded template

Tags: angularjs

I have a template **hsMenuCreateNewTicketContent** and it is dynamically loaded into a div in **hsFrameworkTemplate** in the following way:

```
<div class="active-menu-item-content-page row col-md-12" ng-include src="routeString" 
     ng-show="isMenuContentVisible">

</div>
```

I am searching for a way to use a new controller i.e **hsMenuItemContentController** for the dynamically included template.

I tried using ng-controller to register the controller but I had no luck.
Can anyone please suggest any idea?

EDIT:

My **hsFrameworkTemplate** is as below:

```html
<div class="hs-framework-container row col-md-12">
    <div class="hs-customer-support-icon col-md-1">
        <img ng-src="{{ iconPath }}" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="hs-page-header col-md-10">
        "Hello, how can we help you?"
        <p>Welcome to our support page. Please click one of the following options to begin.</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-transclude class="col-md-12"></div><br/>
    <br/>
    
    <div class="active-menu-item-content-page row col-md-12" ng-include src="routeString" 
         ng-show="isMenuContentVisible">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show the `hsFrameworkTemplate` html file

Comment: okay, editing it in my question

Comment: Check it now @sachilaranawaka

Comment: Where did you try to use the `ng-controller` with no luck? Inside the template?

Comment: I tried using it on the div where I am including the template

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**$compile**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to dynamically attach the controller. Please make sure that the controller should physically available and loaded on your application

```
     element.find(".elementtoattachcontroller").attr('ng-controller', 'your controllername');
                $compile(element.find(".elementtoattachcontroller"))(scope);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where can I add this piece of code? I mean in the controller where the template is being loaded?